# How to open pdf file with other app in WP8.1 RT (c#,vb)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I cant found any answer about my question. I tried one of the solution of WP8
but that didn't worked . it closes my app automatically without opening anything like "Stop Working"

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can ANYONE HELP ME ABOUT MY TOPIC...